# Can't insert texts with ' symbol in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

So I've got this problem where I can't seem to insert texts into my database which contain the following character: ' (as in for example:  It's). I've had this problem before and I just stripped the symbol, but now I really need a solution and nowhere on the entire web or stack overflow I can't seem to find a decent and clear answer.

This is how my data is displayed:

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="text_from_form">
      This is the kind of stuff I need and It's awesome (user input example)
</textarea>
```

---

**PHP**

```
<?php

  $my_text = $_POST["text_from_form"};
  $my_text_new = htmlentities($my_text);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO tableName (text)
  VALUES ('$my_text_new')";
?>
```

**THE ERROR**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's awesome ')' at line 2
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: If you use prepared parameterised statements this shouldn't be a problem. Your script is at risk of [**SQL Injection Attack**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/5914775). Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187/5914775) Use [prepared parameterised statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: @TomUdding can you maybe give an example of what I need to do then? Because I don't understand a word of what you're saying...

Comment: `htmlentities()` going out, not in. And you should use prepared statements - which API are you using to query the database? `mysql_*`? `mysqli_*`? PDO?

Answer (score 0):

The `htmlentities()` function doesn't escape single quotes `'` in default flag (`ENT_COMPACT`), use `htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES)` or function `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `mysqli_real_escape_string()` depending on which library you use.